# What events are available for PrimeFaces DataList

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to capture the Page event when users click through pages using the Paginator on a **DataList**. The user guide doesn't mention any Ajax behaviors for this component, but I tried `<p:ajax event="page">` anyway and found that event "page" is not supported.

Are there any events available for **DataList**? If not, has anyone got an idea how I can save each page as the user pages through?

Thanks :)
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the the component's rendering lifecycle (the component is rerendered with each pagination operation) with the generic `preRenderComponent` event on the datalist. Just add the following to your datalist:

```
   <p:dataList>
      <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{yourBean.operation}"/>
   </p:dataList>
```

Comment: Was able to catch the event thanks @kolossus :). Couldn't get a direct handle to the data on the page the user was leaving, so had to deduce it from the what the current item in the list was using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{item}", MyItem.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to override the standard PrimeFaces javascript function which is called if you click the pagelinks. From there you may call a remoteCommand or whatever you want to...

I know it´s not the best practice, but a possibility ;)

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Paginator.prototype.bindPageLinkEvents = function(){

  var $this = this;

  this.pagesContainer.children('.ui-paginator-page').on('click.paginator', function(e) {
    var link = $(this);

    if(!link.hasClass('ui-state-disabled')&&!link.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
      $this.setPage(parseInt(link.text()) - 1);
    }

    // your code goes here

  })
  .on('mouseover.paginator', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    if(!item.hasClass('ui-state-disabled')&&!item.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
      item.addClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
  })
  .on('mouseout.paginator', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
  })
  .on('focus.paginator', function() {
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-focus');
  })
  .on('blur.paginator', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus');
  })
  .on('keydown.paginator', function(e) {
    var key = e.which,
        keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;

    if((key === keyCode.ENTER||key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER)) {
      $(this).trigger('click');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
};
```

Or look at this answer. I like it very much!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25930991/2265727