# Using the page event with p:dataList in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Does a [`<p:dataList>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml) support the `page` event? I'm trying to use the `page` event in the following way (blocking a `<p:dataList>` using `<pe:blockUI>` while going through pages).

```
<pe:blockUI target="dataList" widgetVar="blockDataListUIWidget">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:graphicImage library="default" name="images/ajax-loader1.gif"/>
        <h:outputText value="Fetching..." class="block-ui-text"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</pe:blockUI>

<p:dataList id="dataList"
            var="orderRow"
            value="#{orderDetailsManagedBean}"
            first="0"
            rows="1"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            type="definition" lazy="true"
            emptyMessage="Message">

    <p:ajax event="page"
            onstart="PF('blockDataListUIWidget').block()" 
            oncomplete="PF('blockDataListUIWidget').unblock()"
            process="@this"
            update="@none"/>

            ...

</p:dataList>
```

This does not work anymore. The page just remains blank with no errors. Events don't seem to be supported by `<p:dataList>`.

Can this scenario be simulated in `<p:dataList>` anyway?

Comment: For the record, blocking a dataList raised a bug in PrimeFaces extensions! it might not be supported! will you try it from your console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have seen from the [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6922ec428149c29b84c66f8934f34001589996e8/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/datalist/DataListTemplate.java#L31) that `page` event is not supported by `dataList`, on the other hand `dataGrid` [supports it](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6922ec428149c29b84c66f8934f34001589996e8/src/main/java-templates/org/primefaces/component/datagrid/DataGridTemplate.java#L25).

The solution would be monkey patching as we don't have control on rewriting the original JS file, you can hook an event before the handling of the pagination and after it, all by javascript.

Here's an example:
assuming your dataList `widgetVar` is `dataListWV`

```
//making sure the widgetVar is ready to be used    
setTimeout(dataListPaginationExtraEvents, 1000);    

function dataListPaginationExtraEvents() {
   var odlHandlePagination = PF('dataListWV').handlePagination;

   PF('dataListWV').handlePagination = function(newState) {
      //before
      console.log('start fetch');
      //calling original pagination 
      odlHandlePagination.apply(this, [newState]);
      //after
      console.log('end fetch');
   }
 }
```

Comment: Browsers refuse to compile the code - `Widget for var 'dataListWV' not available!` `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handlePagination' of undefined`.

Comment: At first I had this problem, but it's really where are placing your js code, anyhow to test it... remove the document.ready and set timeout .. I have updated the answer.

Comment: PrimeFaces Extension `<pe:blockUI>` does not work. PrimeFaces `<p:blockUI block="dataList" widgetVar="blockDataListUIWidget"/>` however, does. What is the reason PrimeFaces Extension's `<pe:blockUI>` does not function? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe something is changed in PF 5.0 that caused the extensions to break out. But from the error message in the console I can see that the selector is failing somehow!

Comment: Do you know, in this case a solution to make a `<p:blockUI>` work after the `<p:dataList>` (or `<p:dataTable>`) which it is associated with is updated via an AJAX request? It is a common problem with `<p:blockUI>` that does not function, when a component which it is associated with is updated via AJAX, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20028923/1391249. Therefore, I never use `<p:blockUI>` except this special case.

Answer (score 0):

As of PrimeFaces 5.3 final (community release), the `page` event is supported in [`<p:dataList>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml)

The following picture is taken from the [PrimeFaces user guide 5.3](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) (page 146).

[image]

There is no mention of Ajax behavior events in previous guides.

The `page` event as mentioned in the question works flawlessly in PrimeFaces 5.3 final (community release).

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/687
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/52b6c22eb37eca62a979d204f2030c82b795d472#diff-b651ae3f3b6abb0cf6945a9c589fa68aR98